# Different standards of ELF (SysV vs TIS) and Linux?

Tags: linux, elf, standard, ld

There are at least two standards of [Executable and Linkable Format
 (ELF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), one of them

- [System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement (With LP64 and ILP32 Programming Models) Version 1.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf)
- [Tool Interface Standard (TIS) Executable and Linking Format (ELF)
  Specification Version 1.2](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf)

The older one, the TIS ELF Standard 1.2 is 106 pages while the SysV ABI is 157 pages but covers ELF only on pages 63-86 (23 pages).

How do these two standards relate to each other? And which one does Linux and GNU Linker use? What is the Tool Interface Standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The TIS/ELF one](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf) covers ELF in general, while [the System V ABI](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) is a supplement which documents the x86_64 Application Binary Interface.

The second document does not contain any information about x86_64 since the architecture didn't exist at the time it was written.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Tool Interface Standard?

ELF format has been selected by the Tool Interface Standards committee (TIS) as a standard for portable object files for a variety of (Unix-Like) operating systems.

> And which one does Linux and GNU Linker use?

Almost all of them use the SystemV standard.

```
name@host:~$ file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```